# selectize drop down to be on first item while typing

Tags: javascript, selectize.js

I'm loading drop-down options remotely, everything works fine except after some typing and deleting text, the drop-down scroller comes to the middle of scroll bar, and not the first option
[image]
how can i force the drop down to always be at the first option after remote call?

Comment: de-select all and select the first item?  A reference to the original of that might assist.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss i didnt select any option. drop down option just  reloaded when user type

Comment: @osyan, have you found any solution ?

Comment: @QubaishBhatti I will post the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by adding scroll in success part of ajax request as below

```
success: function (res) {

    callback(res.results);

    $('.selectize-dropdown-content').animate({ scrollTop: (0) }, 'slow');

},
```